# Move along polyline based on time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am busy with building a kind of 'track' player for GPS Tracks.

I have in my database all the positions of a certain track (latitude, longitude, altitude, time).

I am able to display the whole track on a map and move the marker along that track (see `http://89.188.9.68/nl/gebruikers/track/trackid/101/#.T5AbauxNs1Y`). At the left you have somewher 'starten!!!!'. If you hit that he will move along the track but based on distance.

My goal is that I could move based on time. Final goal is that I have 2 markers, 2 tracks and that I could play it and see the difference between the 2 markers. If i use distance it will be for both the same, but I would see where person 1 (track 1) was and where person 2 was at that moment.

Anyone any idea how i could make this work? Or any idea how this is possible? One of my ideas is that I ask for every movement the position of a certain person (asking it to the database), but isn't that too heavy?

Currently I use v3, but if you think v2 is better for this, i could always switch ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of `setInterval` actually counting time ticks, as shown here

http://jsfiddle.net/KSp4j/

You mentioned querying a database, yet in your example all the points are in the source. What I show needs the data already loaded in the HTML file. I use a format:

```
[
  [time 1st pt. arrived, lat, lng]
  [time 2nd pt. arrived, lat, lng]
  [time 3rd pt. arrived, lat, lng]
   ...
]
```

and check the elapsed time with array's time.

Comment: Interval needs to be 1000, otherwise it is too quick.